# gRPC HelloWorld - Error sending message to ASP.NET Core server from Python client

Tags: python, asp.net-core, grpc

I set up an ASP.NET Core client using this [Tutorial: Create a gRPC client and server in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

My endpoint is at https://localhost:5001
And from what I have read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) it says

> "Kestrel endpoints used for gRPC should be secured with TLS. In
>   development, an endpoint secured with TLS is automatically created at
>   https://localhost:5001 when the ASP.NET Core development certificate
>   is present"

In my python code I have

```
"""The Python implementation of the GRPC helloworld.Greeter client."""

from __future__ import print_function
import logging

import grpc

import greet_pb2
import greet_pb2_grpc


def run():
    # NOTE(gRPC Python Team): .close() is possible on a channel and should be
    # used in circumstances in which the with statement does not fit the needs
    # of the code.
    with grpc.insecure_channel('https://localhost:5001') as channel:
        stub = greet_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
        response = stub.SayHello(greet_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
    print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    run()
```

But when I run it I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "greet_client.py", line 37, in <module>
    run()
  File "greet_client.py", line 31, in run
    response = stub.SayHello(greet_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 824, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 726, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "DNS resolution failed"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1580765368.309000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3941,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580765368.309000000","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":262,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580765368.309000000","description":"DNS resolution failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native/dns_resolver.cc","file_line":202,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1580765368.309000000","description":"OS Error","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":96,"os_error":"No such host is known.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":11001}]}]}]}"
```

Comment: The "No such host is known" error is odd, as localhost is usually easy to find...I'm assuming the client and server are running on the same machine. Did you try connecting to port 5000? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration, the insecure port is 5000, not 5001. If that doesn't help get this solved, can you verify that you're able to successfully connect using the tutorial's included ASP.NET client to help isolate the problem?

Comment: @EricG Yes when I run everything in .NETCore (Client and Server)  just like in the tutorial it works fine, its just when I try connecting from Python.  I think it has to do with the TLS certificate, maybe I have to use secure connection from python and create my own certificate for use on both sides - I think .NET is generating it automatically when debugging.

Comment: According to the aspnet docs, is the server's TLS port. So I would expect you to need to use port 5000 for a plaintext connection - but the WSA 11001 error indicates the problem is occurring even earlier, a failure to resolve localhost. Depending on what Windows environment you're using it looks like this could possibly be a configuration issue, e.g., I was able to find https://superuser.com/questions/713491/why-does-localhost-not-work-in-windows-8-1-but-127-0-0-1-does. You could try digging into your /etc/hosts file or just trying some localhost synonyms, e.g., 0.0.0.0:5000 or 127.0.0.1:5000